# Insert data in 1 table with data from 2 others

Tags: c#, mysql

So I have this:

```
INSERT INTO Track (Trackname, Trackinfo) VALUES (Value1, Value2)
INSERT INTO Artiest (Artist) VALUES (Value1)
```

Both of these tables have an ID that is auto_increment
how can I create a table that will have both the IDs??

I am trying to do this in C#

EDIT: Maybe there is a way in MySQL where I can get the last IDs of the 2 tables?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What have you tried?

Comment: Well since C# doesn't know the ID it creates I don't know how to make another table that will have both IDs in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either write a stored procedure using T-SQL and SCOPE_IDENTITY().
Or you use LINQ to Entities and retrieve the ID of the newly created Entity.

T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @TrackID AS int
INSERT INTO Track (Trackname, Trackinfo) VALUES (Value1, Value2)
SET @TrackID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

DECLARE @ArtiestID AS int
INSERT INTO Artiest (Artist) VALUES (Value1)
SET @ArtiestID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Now use those ID's to Insert into your table.

```
INSERT INTO TrackArtiest (TrackID , ArtiestID ) VALUES (@TrackID , @ArtiestID)
```

When using Linq to Entities:

```
var myTrackObject = new Track(Value1, Value2);
var myArtiestObject= new Artiest(Value1);

// db is your datacontext
db.Tracks.Insert(myTrackObject);
db.Artiests.Insert(myArtiestObject);
db.SubmitChanges();

// You can retrieve the id from the object
int trackID = myTrackObject.ID;
int artiestID = myArtiestObject.ID;

var myTrackArtiest = new TrackArtiest(trackID, artiestID);
db.TrackArtiest.Insert(myTrackArtiest );
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Is this what you meant ?

Comment: Yes thank you. I already tried getting the last IDs with orderby (DESC LIMIT) but it was verry messy, Thanks! sorry I didn't know how to ask it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL and want to return the ID of the insert operation. Use: SCOPE_IDENTITY() function in SQL. But you have to return it and map it to C#